# Java, Using a newly-created Text File

Tags: java, file-io

The code below describes a Java situation. I used some psudocode in the `getRuntime().exec` function; but, the main  point is that a new file is created.

Although the second line causes an error the first time it is run I can see the new file has been created. Also, the 2nd time I run it, it works; I mean to say the 2nd time it is run, it can read the file created on the previous run.  So, the best I can figure is that the 2nd line needs to *wait* until the new file is created (~1,000 lines of text).

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"Do something that writes a new file",  "c:/"+newFileName+".xml"});

...

 File fileToParse = new File("c:/"+newFileName+".xml");
```

Comment: Why not use `File` to create the file on your system? That way you know it is done when the method returns. How about: [`File#createNewFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29)

Comment: I'm using a utility called Nmap that creates the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating files can be done natively in Java using the [`File.createNewFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) method. That is much nicer and clearer.

```
File fileThatShouldBeCreated = new File("C:\\" + newFileName + ".xml");
fileThatShouldBeCreated.createNewFile(); // Create it!
System.out.println(fileThatShouldBeCreated.exists()); // Check if it exists.
```

---

Since you told us that you use a utility which doesn't simply create a file but also write data to it, this doesn't answer the question, of course.

In addition to [JB Nizet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041808/java-using-a-newly-created-text-file/8041861#8041861), I want to tell that I had some problems with the `waitFor()` method. It didn't want to return. I guess it was because of I didn't read all the output of the process (by `stdout`). What do others think about this? Is this a relevant conclusion? I just read the first couple of lines of the output and called `waitFor()`, but there was still a lot of other output after those couple of lines.

Comment: Yes, you need to read the output of the program. Else it hangs trying to write more until the output is read.

Comment: @JBNizet: Is this also needed when you even don't call `Process.getInputStream()`?

Comment: Yes. The stream exists, whether you get it or not. Read http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=2

Answer (score 4):

Wait for the process to terminate using the [`waitFor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) method on the Process returned by `Runtime.exec`. Else, the second line of code executes while the external process is running and hasn't created the file already.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use the new [fork/join](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) approach to concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write this under Java 7 then you can use the new [Path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [WatchService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) functionalities.  You would point to the path and *watch* it to notify you when it is created

```
Path path = new File("c:/"+newFileName+".xml").toPath()
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
path.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);

WatchKey key = watcher.take();//will block here until the file is created
```